# UIScrollView contentSize Issue

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

Within my view I create a scrollview with a width of 320 and a height of 70.

Responding to the user touching a button, I expand the scrollview, so it is 380(h) x 320(w) in size.

The code for this is shown below:

```
CGRect scrollviewFrame = CGRectMake(0, 30, 320, 380);
[scrollView setFrame:scrollviewFrame];
[self layoutScrollImages:YES];
CGSize srect =  CGSizeMake([scrollView bounds].size.width, (kNumImages * kScrollObjHeight));
[scrollView setContentSize:srect];
```

As I debug this project, I can see that srect is 320 (w) x 8000 (h) in size; however my issue is the scrollable area (where the user can actually touch to scroll the scrollview) remains the same as when it was it's original size.

I'm obviously missing something, does anyone know what it is?

Edit: I have created a sample project to illustrate the issue I am having, it is available here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9930498/ScrollViewTest.zip

Comment: I guess You have answered your question, have you increase the content size too, corresponding to the frame size?

Comment: have you increase the contentSize(of your scroll view) too......

Comment: @rptwsthi yes, see the last line of the code snippet above

Comment: The content size will match the targets size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think , you have issue with your below line of code.

```
CGSize srect =  CGSizeMake([scrollView bounds].size.width, (kNumImages * kScrollObjHeight));
   [scrollView setContentSize:srect];
```

debug your program and see the content of **srect** , Also let us know the value of below two constant

`kNumImages`,`kScrollObjHeight` .

Comment: const CGFloat kScrollObjHeight = 80;
const NSUInteger kNumImages = 100;

Comment: srect = width 320 / height 8000

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the contentSize of the scrollview as well as the frame.
Maybe this will help aswell: [UIScrollView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html)

Do this when setting the new size

```
scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
[scrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 30, 320, 380)];
CGSize srect =  CGSizeMake([scrollView bounds].size.width, (kNumImages * kScrollObjHeight));
[scrollView setContentSize:srect];
[self layoutScrollImages:YES];
```

Comment: Dang it.. :) Then I also don't know what to do... :D, sorry

Comment: @Mick do you mean to say that even the sample code above has the same problem?

Comment: No I mean to say that it isnt really applicable to my scenario. I have created an example project to illustrate the issue I am having, you can grab it from here http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9930498/ScrollViewTest.zip